# Can anyone solve this recurrence equation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I would like to model compound interest where in each period part of the existing capital can be used to increase the annual interest rate. At first I tried to model this in a way such that in each step the optimal amount of capital would be used to increase the rate, but the equations quickly became exceedingly complex, so now I am trying to model the case where a percentage is fixed beforehand and in each period that percentage of capital is used to increase the rate, so

$x[t]:=x[t-1]*(1+\frac{r+ab\sum_{i=0}^{t-1} x[i]}{t_{max}})-bx[t-1]$

where $x[k]$ is the amount of capital at step $k$, $r$ is the initial rate, $a$ is some parameter regulating the efficiency with which capital can be converted into increase of interest rate, $b$ is the percentage of capital used at each step to increase the annual rate and $t_{max}$ is the amount of periods in a year, which I would ideally like to use to derive the continuous formula afterwards. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: For me it looks very tricky and I would be surprised if there is a closed form; in particular because of the sum term. If $ab=0$, this would be a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I thought it looked tricky too. The problem is that the sum term is essential for the question, it describes how capital is used to raise the interest rate.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas.

The continuous formulation looks like

$$
\dot x = \left(\frac{r+ab\int_0^t x(\tau)d\tau}{t_{max}}-b\right)x
$$

or

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\ln x = \left(\frac{r+ab\int_0^t x(\tau)d\tau}{t_{max}}-b\right)
$$

or

$$
x = C_0 e^{\left(\frac{r}{t_{max}}-b\right)t}e^{\int_0^t\left(\frac{ab\int_0^{\tau} x(\eta)d\eta}{t_{max}}\right)d\tau}
$$

Now calling $\gamma = C_0$ this integral equation can be solved iteratively because it is a contraction then the sequence

$$
x_0(t) = x^0\\
x_{k+1}(t) = \gamma e^{\left(\frac{r}{t_{max}}-b\right)t}e^{\int_0^t\left(\frac{ab\int_0^{\tau} x_k(\eta)d\eta}{t_{max}}\right)d\tau}
$$

converges to a fixed function.

Attached a MATHEMATICA script showing the convergence

```
a = 1; tmax = 20; b = 2/tmax; r = 1;
x0 = 1;
gamma = 1;
Itera[x_, t_, tmax_] := Module[{f, f1, f2}, 
    f = FunctionInterpolation[x, {t, 0., tmax}]; 
    f1 = Integrate[f[t], t];
    f2 = Integrate[f1, t];
    Return[Exp[-(b - r/tmax) t] Exp[a b/tmax f2]]
]
x1 = gamma Itera[x0, t, tmax];
x2 = gamma Itera[x1, t, tmax];
x3 = gamma Itera[x2, t, tmax];
x4 = gamma Itera[x3, t, tmax];
Plot[{x0, x1, x2, x3, x4}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thank you, this helps quite a bit. For some reason I did not receive a notification email for this answer.